# When were achievements, especially their timestamps, introduced to Steam?

Tags: steam, achievements, gaming-history

I need to know for a [project](https://completionist.me/steam/profile/76561197962872631/history) centered around achievements, furthermore the date they were unlocked. I want to mitigate the fact that some achievements before a certain date had no timestamps for statistical reasons.

The earliest indication of an exact date that achievements were assigned timestamps I could find is **[2008-10-25](http://www.astats.nl/Forum/viewtopic.php?f=3&t=336&start=10#p3398)** but I could not find any official statements so far. Is there an earlier known and/or even official date?

In addition, what's the exact date that Steam achievement became available in general (without timestamps that is)?

Comment: Taking a look at [Steam's news/changelog page](http://store.steampowered.com/news/?feed=steam_client) sounds like an interesting idea for that.

Comment: interesting indeed. the first news entry I could find yesterday was from february 2010 though (when browsing steamcommunity.com's mobile site)

Comment: browsing the steam forums archive I could at least find out that showing timestamps was discussed in may 2009 http://forums.steampowered.com/forums/archive/index.php/t-866764.html

Comment: One of the first games with an achievement was probably a Valve one, so maybe you should look around at those. :)

Comment: @Beminfire your are right -  it has to be one of Half-Life 2: Episode Two, Portal or Team Fortress 2 as seen in my updated question

Comment: @luchaos Awesome, we have the answer. I guess you can answer your own question now.

Comment: @Beminfire thanks, I'll post it then - I still would like to know when the first ever recorded achievement unlock on Steam happened :) I'd have to contact Valve directly to find out I guess

Comment: Why was this question downvoted? It doesn't look poorly researched to me, even in its earliest edit.

Comment: @MarchHo it was downvoted several times - I'd love to know, too. I checked several times that there is no obvious answer or similar question availble. I guess the initial link to the project was misinterpreted as promotion of the site.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

According to a [GiantBomb article](http://www.giantbomb.com/steam-achievements/3015-3280/) Steam achievements were introduced with [The Orange Box](http://store.steampowered.com/sub/469/), which was released **2007-10-09**. Half-Life 2: Episode Two, Portal and Team Fortress 2 were the first games to add them.

As far as my research goes there is no indication there's an official date that they had timestamps added explicitly afterwards. Exposing the timestamps in the Steam community data xml feed was discussed in **[2009](http://forums.steampowered.com/forums/archive/index.php/t-866764.html)** (forum was taken offline in 2017). One may assume that timestamps for achievements existed long before that as unlocked achievements were already displayed in daily summaries in the then available blotter feed.

**UPDATE:**

According to the data gathered during [completionist.me](https://completionist.me) development the earliest unlock date is **2008-09-11.**